# Odds of Queen High Flush Being Beat

Tags: flush

So I just got knocked out of a tourney and have a few questions regarding my play.
I'm new to online poker, only playing a little bit of live poker as a kid with friends and family and totally new to tournaments, but I've studied the game quite a bit and think I have a good grasp.
Was the following play good? What should I have done differently?

I'm in the big blind with Q10 suited clubs. Everybody folds but one guy right of the small blind, who limps. I three bet preflop, he calls. Table flops 5 10 J of clubs, with me getting middle pair and a flush draw. I pot it, he calls. 9 of clubs comes on the term, I make my flush with a straight flush draw. I have a feeling I should've checked here to get a feel for him, but opted to jam because about 1/4 of my stack was already in. He calls, with a Kclubs and Jsomething, river comes a 2d, I lose to his K high flush. Like I said, I think checking the turn might've been better, what do you think?

Comment: a bit confused on what happened in the hand, you have QcTc in your hand so the T on the flop was not a club. the 9c and the 2d makes for 3 clubs on the board after the river making his flush impossible as he only has 1 club. would appreciate it if you could clarify.

Comment: In general though, you have the 3rd nuts on the turn given that you had a Q high flush. It's important to know what the stack sizes and pot size are in this hand because that does change things. If you had a short stack that is a fraction of the pot you would jam without much thought, but if you had a large stack you may want to consider checking (if you think he is likely to bet) or betting smaller to extract more value from your flush. Just so happens he woke up with a better flush this time.

Comment: Oh shoot, so sorry, I messed up the flop:
Flop: 5c 10d jc
The rest was correct.
I do not know the exact pot size, nor my exact stack; sorry will be sure to do that next time(this is my first post). I do know I jammed bec. a good portion of my chips were already in the pot, and I didn't include that the other guy was chip leader and bullying. I think I made the correct decision, and like you said, just happened to be going against a guy with a higher flush. Thanks for your answer!